# TypeScript Generics

Tags: generics, typescript, mapped-types

I'm struggling with how to strongly type some functionality with TypeScript.

Essentially I have a function that accepts a key/value map of DataProviders and returns a key/value map of the data returned from each. Here's a simplified version of the problem:

```
interface DataProvider<TData> {
    getData(): TData;
}

interface DataProviders {
    [name: string]: DataProvider<any>;
}

function getDataFromProviders<TDataProviders extends DataProviders>(
    providers: TDataProviders): any {

    const result = {};

    for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(providers)) {
        result[name] = providers[name].getData();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Currently `getDataFromProviders` has a return type of `any` but I want it so that if called like so...

```
const values = getDataFromProviders({
    ten: { getData: () => 10 },
    greet: { getData: () => 'hi' }
});
```

...then `values` will be implicitly strongly typed as:

```
{
    ten: number;
    greet: string;
}
```

I imagine this would involve returning a generic type with a generic parameter of `TDataProviders` but I can't quite work it out.

This is the best I can come up with but doesn't compile...

```
type DataFromDataProvider<TDataProvider extends DataProvider<TData>> = TData;

type DataFromDataProviders<TDataProviders extends DataProviders> = {
    [K in keyof TDataProviders]: DataFromDataProvider<TDataProviders[K]>;
}
```

I'm struggling coming up with a `DataFromDataProvider` type that compiles without me passing in `TData` explicitly as a second parameter, which I don't think I can do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the number of providers is fixed and relatively small (<= 10), best thing I can come up with is by changing getDataFromProviders to use variadic arguments, use phantom type to encode the key ("ten", "greet"). Lots of boilerplate but it gives what you want: https://gist.github.com/evansb/7afc5ac7e640a06759276f456970e857

Comment: Thanks @EvanSebastian, that's an interesting approach. I didn't know you could write `[K in K2]` where K2 is something other than an array. The resulting type is exactly what I want, but the code doesn't work. This approach loses the physical names of data providers. I could make each provider return their names but I want to keep it DRY.

Comment: Oh, I just copy pasted your code, you need to modify it obviously. I should have left the implementation blank, my bad.

Yeah it's not possible to make each provider return their type and get a string literal type from it, unfortunately. I believe you need existential type for that

Comment: No worries. I was thinking about the `[K1 in K2]` bit more and realised `K2` is not an array but a union of string values, and a single string could be considered a union with just one one value in the set. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine that you have a type that maps provider name to the data type returned by the provider. Something like this:

```
interface TValues {
    ten: number;
    greet: string;
}
```

Note that you **don't actually have to define this type**, just imagine it exists, and use it as generic parameter, named `TValues`,  everywhere:

```
interface DataProvider<TData> {
    getData(): TData;
}

type DataProviders<TValues> = 
    {[name in keyof TValues]: DataProvider<TValues[name]>};


function getDataFromProviders<TValues>(
    providers: DataProviders<TValues>): TValues {

    const result = {};

    for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(providers)) {
        result[name] = providers[name].getData();
    }

    return result as TValues;
}


const values = getDataFromProviders({
    ten: { getData: () => 10 },
    greet: { getData: () => 'hi' }
});
```

magically (in fact, using [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types), as @Aris2World pointed out), typescript is able to infer correct types:

```
let n: number = values.ten;
let s: string = values.greet;
```

**update**: as pointed out by the author of the question, `getDataFromProviders` in the code above does not really check that each property of the object it receives conforms to `DataProvider` interface.

For example, if `getData` is misspelled, there is no error, just empty object type is inferred as return type of `getDataFromProviders` (so you will still get an error when you try to access the result, however).

```
const values = getDataFromProviders({ ten: { getDatam: () => 10 } });

//no error, "const values: {}" is inferred for values
```

There is a way to make typescript to detect this error earlier, at the expense of additional complexity in `DataProviders` type definition:

```
type DataProviders<TValues> = 
    {[name in keyof TValues]: DataProvider<TValues[name]>}
   & { [name: string]: DataProvider<{}> };
```

The intersection with [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) adds a requirement that every property of `DataProviders` must be compatible with `DataProvider<{}>`. It uses empty object type `{}` as generic argument for `DataProvider` because `DataProvider` has the nice property that for any data type `T`,  `DataProvider<T>` is compatible with `DataProvider<{}>` - `T` is the return type of `getData()`, and any type is compatible with empty object type `{}`.

Comment: That is a really neat solution!

Comment: I consider this a good advanced example of mapped types. I think that your post will be perfect if you could substitute 'magically' with an explanation or a reference to the documentation ;)

Comment: Type inference in the absence of generics is relatively well documented in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html). Unfortunately there is only one short paragraph about type inference for [generics here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), and there is no mention about its limits. The magic is in getting what you want while staying within undocumented limits - if you push compiler too hard it starts inferring empty object type `{}` or even worse, `any`, so `--noImplicitAny` is a must if you rely on type inference.

Comment: Thanks @artem, nice work. There was only one imperfection I noticed - the compiler doesn't seem to tightly enforce consumers of `getDataFromProviders` to pass parameters in the form of `{ [name: string]: DataProvider<any> }`. So you can pass in a spelling mistake e.g. `{ ten: { getDatam: () => 10 } }` and it compiles, only erroring if you try to use the result like `result.ten` because TS thinks the result is now `{}`. If the compiler would error when making the call with the wrong params it would be perfect!

Comment: There is a way to detect the spelling mistakes earlier, not sure if it worth the additional complexity however. I updated the answer.

Comment: @artem I think this reference could be suitable for the case [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) in particular the paragraph titled "Mapped Types", the example with proxy when it shows unproxify.

Comment: @Aris2World thanks,  totally missed that. I updated the answer.

Comment: @artem that is exactly the behaviour I was looking for. You've actually got me wondering whether I can apply this solution to other similar problems I've had with mapped types! Thank you so much, bounty well earned! 

Comment: @artem, I'm curious if you have some creative ideas on stackoverflow.com/q/46596846/678505, which I think take TS mapped types even to the next level :-)